# Querying XML nested nodes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, xml

I need to integrate a daily XML file into my system.

The XML file has an schema similar to this:

```
create table txml(id int identity, data xml);
insert into txml (data) values ('
<order>
    <trans DTrans="20170102" HTrans="10:52"></trans>
    <head Id="552665566"></head>
    <lin headId="552665566">
        <dLin Id="00001" CoArt="1111111" CoArtCust="05220001" NameArt="Product1" dateVal="20161115" />
        <acum DCalAcm="20170101" DIniAcm="20161115"><qtyAcm Qty="1101163.00" /></acum>
        <lastOrd Id="95767" QtyLastOrd="12000.00" DLastOrd="20170101" />
        <pLin LType="4"><uni Qty="24000.00"/><dIni Date="20170104"/><dEnd Date="20170108"/></pLin>
        <pLin LType="4"><uni Qty="20000.00"/><dIni Date="20170109"/><dEnd Date="20170112"/></pLin>
        <pLin LType="4"><uni Qty="24000.00"/><dIni Date="20170113"/><dEnd Date="20170116"/></pLin>
    </lin>
    <lin headId="552665566">
        <dLin Id="00002" CoArt="2222222" CoArtCust="05269958" NameArt="Product2" dateVal="20161101" />
        <acum DCalAcm="20170101" DIniAcm="20161101"><qtyAcm Qty="552652.00" /></acum>
       <lastOrd Id="49956" QtyLastOrd="5000.00" DLastOrd="20170101" />
        <pLin LType="4"><uni Qty="2200.00"/><dIni Date="20170104"/><dEnd Date="20170108"/></pLin>
        <pLin LType="4"><uni Qty="3000.00"/><dIni Date="20170109"/><dEnd Date="20170116"/></pLin>
    </lin>
</order>');
```

As you can see for each `<lin>` section you can find an unknown number of `<pLin>` lines. By now I'm doing this job using C# and a .Net console app, but I'd like to do it by using SQL.

Till now I can get a rowset of `<lin>` tags using the next query:

```
SELECT  T2.lin.value('(./dLin/@Id)[1]', 'int') Id,
        T2.lin.value('(./dLin/@CoArt)[1]', 'varchar(20)') CoArt,
        T2.lin.value('(./dLin/@CoArtCust)[1]', 'varchar(20)') CoArtCust,
        T2.lin.value('(./lastOrd/@Id)[1]',  'varchar(20)') lastOrderId,
        T2.lin.value('(./lastOrd/@QtyLastOrd)[1]',  'decimal(18,2)') QtyLastOrd
FROM    txml
CROSS APPLY data.nodes('/order/lin') as T2(lin);
```

That produces next result:

```
Id | CoArt   | CoArtCust | lastOrderId | QtyLastOrd
-: | :------ | :-------- | :---------- | :---------
 1 | 1111111 | 05220001  | 95767       | 12000.00  
 2 | 2222222 | 05269958  | 49956       | 5000.00
```

But I should add nested lines corresponding to `<pLin>` tags and produce the next result:

```
Id | CoArt   | CoArtCust | lastOrderId | QtyLastOrd | DIni       | DEnd       | NextQty  
-: | :------ | :-------- | :---------- | :--------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------
 1 | 1111111 | 05220001  | 95767       | 12000.00   | 04/01/2017 | 08/01/2017 | 24000.00  
 1 | 1111111 | 05220001  | 95767       | 12000.00   | 09/01/2017 | 12/01/2017 | 20000.00  
 1 | 1111111 | 05220001  | 95767       | 12000.00   | 13/01/2017 | 16/01/2017 | 24000.00  
 2 | 2222222 | 05269958  | 49956       | 5000.00    | 04/01/2017 | 08/01/2017 | 2200.00  
 2 | 2222222 | 05269958  | 49956       | 5000.00    | 09/01/2017 | 16/01/2017 | 3000.00
```

I've set up a *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ce1a9e50a70082a7d95e8e1cb2a6c474)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add an additional `CROSS APPLY` to break out the rows in the way you require:

```
SELECT  T2.lin.value('(./dLin/@Id)[1]', 'int') Id,
        T2.lin.value('(./dLin/@CoArt)[1]', 'varchar(20)') CoArt,
        T2.lin.value('(./dLin/@CoArtCust)[1]', 'varchar(20)') CoArtCust,
        T2.lin.value('(./lastOrd/@Id)[1]',  'varchar(20)') lastOrderId,
        T2.lin.value('(./lastOrd/@QtyLastOrd)[1]', 'decimal(18,2)') QtyLastOrd,
        T3.lin.value('(./dIni/@Date)[1]', 'date') DIni,
        T3.lin.value('(./dEnd/@Date)[1]', 'date') DEnd,
        T3.lin.value('(./uni/@Qty)[1]', 'decimal(7, 2)') DIni
FROM    txml
CROSS APPLY data.nodes('/order/lin') as T2(lin)
CROSS APPLY T2.lin.nodes('pLin') as T3(lin);
```

I had to guess the datatype for DIni, correct as required.